# Button changing classes and starting animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I've a got a stepper to develop and I'm having trouble getting the slide out section to retract then the steps button at the top is pressed a second time.

[Here's a link to a pen](http://codepen.io/sharperwebdev/pen/meVNOe)

Any advice would be welcome

```
var hiddenSteps = ".hiddenSteps";

$(".expandButton").click(function() {
  TweenMax.to(hiddenSteps, 0.5, {left:50, ease:Back.easeOut});
  $(this).addClass("collapseButton").removeClass("expandButton");
});
$(".collapseButton").click(function() {
  TweenMax.to(hiddenSteps, 0.5, {left:-80});
  $(this).removeClass("collapseButton").addClass("expandButton");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method as you change the elements classes dynamically:

```
var hiddenSteps = ".hiddenSteps";

$(document).on('click', '.expandButton', function() {
  TweenMax.to(hiddenSteps, 0.5, {left:50, ease:Back.easeOut});
  $(this).addClass("collapseButton").removeClass("expandButton");
});
$(document).on('click', '.collapseButton', function() {
  TweenMax.to(hiddenSteps, 0.5, {left:-80});
  $(this).removeClass("collapseButton").addClass("expandButton");
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvqNjE

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you!!